# When using linqtosql, and inner joining, can you return only a subset of columns?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When using linqtosql, and inner joining, can you return only a subset of columns or does it pull in all the column/properties?

Sometimes you need just 2-3 columns, having it pull back all 15 etc. seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

sure

```
var query =
  from c in db.Customers
  join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
  select new {c.Name, o.OrderDate};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what projections (anonymous types are for).  You simply have to do:

```
from p in People
select new { p.Name, p.Age }
```

With a join it is possible to still use anonymous types.  If you want to represent the one-to-many relationship, you simply do:

```
var query =
  from c in db.Customers
  join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into g
  select new {c.Name, Orders = g };
```

However, this has the result of causing you to execute a new query to the database the first time the Orders are accessed for a customer.

If you simply want to flatten the structure, remove the grouping, and then just project into the new anonymous type, [like others have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059969/when-using-linqtosql-and-inner-joining-can-you-return-only-a-subset-of-columns/1060010#1060010):

```
var query =
  from c in db.Customers
  join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
  select new {c.Name, o.OrderDate};
```

Comment: can you do something similiar with nhibernate?

Comment: @Blankman: I'm not that familiar with NHibernate, so I can't say for sure.